# Touchable onPress with React Native Navigation not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation, arrow-functions

The below code works and when clicked takes me the loginStack Stack Navigator

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback 
    onPress={ this.navigateToScreen('loginStack') }>
        <View><Text>Click Me</Text></View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

My NavigateToScreen function looks like this

```
navigateToScreen = (route) => () => {
        const navigationAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: route
        })
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigationAction)
    }
```

Since I need to manage multiple stuff, I converted it to an arrow function and it doesn't work. The below code does nothing when pressed. No response at all.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback 
    onPress={ () => this.navigateToScreen('loginStack') }>
        <View><Text>Click Me</Text></View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

How do I fix this so I can run multiple lines of code on the onPress function like given below?

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback 
    onPress={ () => { this.navigateToScreen('loginStack') 
                      AsyncStorage.removeItem('token') 
                    }}>
        <View><Text>Click Me</Text></View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `navigateToScreen` function is returning another function, which in your working example is the function being called when pressed. Where you changed onPress to an arrow function, you are calling `navigateToScreen`  but not the function it returns.

Changing it to

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback 
    onPress={ () => {
        this.navigateToScreen('loginStack')()
        AsyncStorage.removeItem('token')
}}>
    <View><Text>Click Me</Text></View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

should work, or you could remove the second arrow function in your `navigateToScreen` function so it no longer returns a function but executes the code itself

```
navigateToScreen = (route) => {
        const navigationAction = NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName: route
        })
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigationAction)
    }
```

I would recommend this option, but keep in mind your currently working example would no longer work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

TouchableWithoutFeedback always needs to have child View component.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={ this.navigateToScreen('loginStack') }}>
  <View>
      <Text>Click Me</Text>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Comment: I have edited the code to contain View as child. It still doesn't seem to work though!

Comment: I think now this two link will help to find solution https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback.html and https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10180